# Why does `puts {}.class.name` return nothing in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class

I've tried this with other classes and they return things. Just this one doesn't.

```
puts ''.class.name # String
puts 1.class.name  # Integer
puts [].class.name # Array
puts {}.class.name
```

but `{}.class.name` just returns blank.

Comment: `puts {}` evaluates `nil` and `nil.class.name` evaluates  to the string "NilClass", as you can see by, i.e. `x=puts {}; p x`, or in one statement, by doing a `puts(puts {}).class.name`. Note that if you have a method `f`,  the expression `f {}` invokes `f` by passing the block to it, while `f({})` invokes `f` by passing a Hash to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `puts {}` passes a block.

Any method can take a block.

`puts {}.class.name` is really `(puts {}).class.name`.  `puts {}` ignores the block and prints a newline. It returns `nil`. `class.name` is called on `nil` so the return value is `NilClass`. But that doesn't get passed to `puts` so it's not printed.

We can see it in IRB.

```
> puts {}.class.name

 => "NilClass"
```

Use parens to clarify. `puts({}.class.name)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `{}` is interpreted as a block sent to `puts`.

`class.name` is executed when `puts` returns, and the value is discarded.